# Problems which are solvable using Linear Programming

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming

Can anyone share a link to a good survey/book about the different problem types for which we have a linear programming based solution for, as well as the related techniques?

Comment: What research have you done on your own before asking?  This site often isn't a great match for "book recommendation" requests, especially if you don't define objective criteria to evaluate answers by ("good" is not enough).

Comment: My question was edited. the original description was along the lines: "I have browsed through and forgotten linear optimization tricks again and again. Is there any collection of problems of various type that can be solved via linear programming? Where you just have problems, and their solutions, so you get an overview of various techniques."
In my mind this is similar to "Counterexamples in Probability and Real Analysis" just problems to highlight the tricks. I searched on my own but could only find books of a textbook nature.

Comment: Got it.  If the revision does not accurately reflect your intent, you are welcome to roll back the revision or edit the edit to better match what you are looking for.  (That said, you might also want to tell us what research you have done on your own.  Have you spent some time searching through candidates on Amazon or other book sites, to look for ones that might be suitable?)

Comment: I found [Linear programming tricks](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms3om_linearprogrammingtricks.pdf) and it seemed useful. I also got numerous small documents when searching for "linear programming modelling" which weren't comprehensive enough. Is there any alternate forum I could also try this request in?

Comment: Check the chapter notes at the end of linear programming chapter of CLRS. Also there are a number of courses dedicated to linear programming online that you can check. ps: I think RB's edit was reasonable. Btw, please check [tour] and [help/on-topic] of you are new on the site.

Comment: I had no qualms with the edit, and chose to retain it. The newer version, however, might have seemed a bit vague to DW (as evidenced by his first comment), so I chose to clarify by posting the previous version as well.

Comment: Boyd's Convex Optimization is a great resource on general approaches to solving convex optimization problems. There is a good bit of coverage on LPs.